# Jacobi elliptic function formula

Tags: complex-analysis, elliptic-functions

Jacobi defined the elliptic function by

$u=\int_0^{\phi}\frac{d\theta}{\sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2(\theta)}}$
,$am(u)=\phi,sn(u)=\sin(am(u)),cn(u)=\cos(am(u))$

$dn(u)=\sqrt{1-k^2sn^2(u)},k'^2+k^2=1$

and he set
$K=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{d\theta}{\sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2(\theta)}},K'=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{d\theta}{\sqrt{1-k'^2\sin^2(\theta)}}$

then he listed without proof these five formulas:

$\sin(am(K-u))=\frac{cn(u)}{dn(u)},\cos(am(K-u))=\frac{k'sn(u)}{dn(u)},\frac{d(am(K-u))}{du}=\frac{k'}{dn(u)}$

$\tan(am(K-u))=1/(k'\tan(am(u)),\cot(am(K-u))=k'/\cot(am(u))$

I tried a lot but can't figure out how these are deduced? I used the addition
formula but it didn't work. Can anyone give a detailed deduction about these formulas?

Comment: what is your am, sn ?

Comment: When you used the addition formula, you would evaluate each elliptic function at $K$ like [this](https://functions.wolfram.com/EllipticFunctions/JacobiSN/03/01/02/01/0002/) and at $u$. What trouble did you have?

Comment: It is not so fortunate to use the same symbol for the integration variable and the upper limit of integration.

Comment: @MathFail   am is defined by the first and second formula, it is the inversion of the first formula

Comment: @Gary you can think as they are different, there is not distinction.